# Magento widget with WYSIWYG editor

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cms, wysiwyg, widget

I'm creating a custom magento widget with the WYSIWYG editor as a widget option.

I followed those two pages as initial setup
http://www.behrendt.io/2013/04/12/using-a-wysiwyg-editor-in-a-magento-widget/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767894/magento-add-wysiwyg-editor-to-custom-widget/15953843#15953843

Currently I see the editor appearing, but by saving the widget I run into some errors.

First of all there is the text attribute missing in the widget declaration

```
{{widget type="widgetone/slideshow"}}
```

When i try to save the widget i get the following javascript alert

[image]

I already looked in the web but didn't found anything helpful.

I'm using magento **CE 1.7.0.2** and here you can see my widget code:

widget.xml

```
 <company_widgetone_slideshow type="widgetone/slideshow" translate="name description">
    <name>Slideshow</name>
    <description type="desc">Description</description>
     <parameters>
     <text translate="label">
        <label>Text</label>
        <visible>1</visible>
        <type>widgetone/widget_wysiwyg</type>
    </text>
    </parameters>
</company_widgetone_slideshow>
```

My widget block

```
class Company_WidgetOne_Block_Widget_Wysiwyg extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element {
public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{

    Mage::log("block");
    $editor = new Varien_Data_Form_Element_Editor($element->getData());

    // Prevent foreach error
    $editor->getConfig()->setPlugins(array());

    $editor->setId($element->getId());
    $editor->setForm($element->getForm());

    $editor->setWysiwyg(true);
    $editor->setForceLoad(true);

    return parent::render($editor);
} }
```

If i try to override the magento Widget Model (as showen in the second link above)

```
class Company_WidgetOne_Model_Widget extends Mage_Widget_Model_Widget {
public function getWidgetDeclaration($type, $params = array(), $asIs = true)
{
    Mage::log($params);

    if( preg_match('~(^widgetone/slideshow)~', $type) )
    {
        $params['text'] = str_replace('"', "'", $params['text']);
    }

    return parent::getWidgetDeclaration($type, $params, $asIs);
}
}
```

The `$params` array is always empty ..

Also the post-parameter `parameters[text]`in the ajax call when saving the widget is empty

[image]

Please provide any possible idea you have to solve this issue

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a direct answer to your question but in the past when I have needed the user to be able to include html via the widget tool what I have done is to include cms blocks using the built in block chooser. Then the user can simply add the block and then link it in via the widget.

I know that this could be a pain as the user has to use two different systems but then in my opinion you get a smoother system as a lot of our users have issues with widgets and loosing the content of widgets.